# What is difference between fill='both' and fill=tk.BOTH in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
mylabel=ttk.Label(root,text="This is a label")
mylabel.pack(expand="true",fill=tk.BOTH)
```

What is difference between fill='both' and fill=tk.BOTH in tkinter

Comment: I think they are both the same, just another way of referencing it.

Comment: `BOTH` is defined as `"both"`, so they are the same.

Comment: use `print(tk.BOTH)` and you'll come to know that tk.BOTH is defined as 'both'

Comment: i tried it thank you so much guys <3

Answer (score 0):

> What is difference between fill='both' and fill=tk.BOTH in tkinter

Nothing. The tkinter constant `BOTH` is simply the string "both". Whether you use the constant or a string constant, both cases set the attribute to the literal string "both".

You can verify this yourself with the following statements:

```
assert type(tk.BOTH) is str
assert tk.BOTH == "both"
```

Personally I see absolutely no value in using the tkinter constants like `BOTH`, `END`, etc. They all are just set to a literal string, so you might as well use the literal string.